# How to sort results from two databases

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I have two web services; an ASP/SQL server web service and a PHP/MySQL web service.

I need to get results from both services combined in an XML and results need to be paginated (limited to 10 results a page). Now how do I order the results (e.g., alphabetically) when they are coming from two separate databases?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what technology you are using to fetch both queries here, but nevertheless:

You could query both databases, and then merge the query result manually (perhaps creating a hash with the results from both queries in PHP). Then you could sort the hash, and output the results needed for the current page. You'll want to cache these results somehow if you are working with a lot of data, and doing this often.

Or, you could pull the data that you need from one database into the other, and perform a UNION query. This would require you to fetch that data every so often, and that time will depend on what you are doing and how fresh you need the data to be.

Comment: I am using a PHP front end that gets results from both web services (one an ASP.net web service and a PHP web service). How will I transfer data from one database into another?

Comment: How often will you need to sync the data? There are many ways to pull it over but not knowing what you are doing and the frequency makes it hard to determine what solution to suggest. If you only need to copy the data once, you could use a SQL server tool to extract the data from one database, and then you could modify it and insert it into a temporary table in the other database. If you are going to be doing this a lot, you would benefit from merging the data into one database.

Comment: its a search engine; so needs to be done every time the user initiates a search. Data may be also be added to any of the two databases at anytime.